# Using trigonometry to animate HTML5 canvas, but how to position this square?

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, trigonometry

Sometimes you wish you could go back in time to tell your younger self that maths are indeed important! But I doubt I would've listened back then. I've been playing with trigonometry lately for animation purposes with the HTML5 canvas in this particular example.

It's a super simple animation: It positions an arc in a circular manner around the center of the canvas. The X and Y positions are calculated based upon the basic trigonometry functions sinus and cosinus. "SohCahToa". I think I'm starting to get it. But somehow I cannot figure out how to draw a square in the middle of one of the triangular sides.

[image: GIF showing the problem.]

```
let radius = 200;
let angle = 0;
x = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radius;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(x/2, centerY, 20, 20);
```

https://codepen.io/melvinidema/pen/wvKPepa?editors=1010

So the arc is drawn by adding up the center of the canvas with the 
rework formulas: (co)sinus - for X = Cos, for Y = Sin) of the angle times the radius of the circle.

If we only take the X position (red line) and want to draw the square half of the position of the arc. ( So in **the middle of the red line** ) we should just be able to divide the freshly calculated X position by two right? But if I do that, the square is magically drawn completely outside the circle.

What's happening? Why does it behave like this? And what calculation should I use instead for the square to position in the middle of the red line throughout the animation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` defined as:

```
x = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radius;
```

but when you want to divide by 2, you just need to divide the `Math.cos(angle) * radius`, while the `centerX` is the zero point, and its stand as it is.

So the rect should be placed at:

```
centerX + Math.cos(angle)/2
```

Also, I think will be better if you reduce half of the rect width, and get:

```
centerX + Math.cos(angle)/2 - 10
```

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let radius = 200;

function frame(angle) {
  const cx = canvas.width / 2,
  cy = canvas.height / 2,
  x = Math.cos(angle) * radius,
  y = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);
  ctx.lineTo(cx+x, cy+y);
  ctx.lineTo(cx+x, cy);
  ctx.lineTo(cx, cy);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx+x, cy+y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillRect(cx + x/2 - 10, cy - 10, 20, 20);
  ctx.closePath();
  requestAnimationFrame(()=>frame(angle+.03));
}
frame(0)
```

```css
canvas {
display: block;
max-height: 100vh;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ah indeed! Thank you for the provided example and different perspective of the code. I've figured out what I did wrong after a small break and your code helped a lot! The square is just a small circle. So dividing the radius in half would've solved the problem as well.